# Download zip file from httpresponse not working

Tags: java, servlets, zip

I want to be able to download a zip file from a web page through a Java servlet.

This code works, i can download a zip file and open it with winrar. But if i try to open it with 7zip it says `Cannot open file: it does not appear to be valid archive`

Here is the code :

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+"test.zip");
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setContentLength(briefcaseService.getContentLength(item, sessionView.getLogAsUser()));
OutputStream ouputStream;
try {
            ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            briefcaseService.loadReportContentFromReportInstance(item, ouputStream, reportName, sessionView.getLogAsUser());
            fc.responseComplete();
} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does the problem come from this part of the code or it can come from the `loadReportContnetFromReportInstance` method?

If you need any information feel free to ask. Thanks

EDIT : Here is the method loadReportContentFromReportInstance().

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(bos);


// Récupération du document attaché au report
OxwayDocument docWithAttachement = reportManager.findReportAttachementFromReportInstance(reportInstance, user, reportDef);

if (docWithAttachement.equals(null) || docWithAttachement.getAttachFile().equals(null)) {
    return;
}

ZipEntry zipEntryReport = new ZipEntry(fileName);
zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntryReport);
zipOut.write(Base64.decode(docWithAttachement.getAttachFile().getBytes()));

zipOut.close();
bos.close();
outputStream.write(Base64.decode(docWithAttachement.getAttachFile().getBytes()));

final PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(outputStream, true, "UTF-8");

ps.flush();
ps.write(bos.toByteArray());

ps.flush();
```

Comment: Please show us the implementation of `loadReportContentFromReportInstance`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i edited the post. If you need something more please ask me.

Comment: Why are you writing out a Base64 decoded attachment into the `outputStream` and why are you doing an UTF-8 PrintStream to write out the zip bytes?

Comment: In fact, why not just use `new ZipOutputStream(outputStream)`?

Comment: @akarnokd I don't know, but i tried and it worked. Thanks !